# Why my data from my mongoDb volume is being cleaned every 2-3 weeks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile, digital-ocean

I launched a website on digital ocean thanks to docker.
I have a database which is stored in my mongodb volume.
My api is made with NodeJS, all post and patch requests are authenticated by a JWT.

The problem is that every 2-3 weeks my mongodb collections are erased from my volume, like if they were deleted by someone.

Do you have an idea where the problem could come from?

Here the docker-compose file :
[image: docker compose file]

Comment: Are you adding any field with key name as exp to store date, if yes this auto-deletes (the only trigger in mongoDB) the data at that specific time

Comment: The only way I store date is "Year-Month-Day"